# Wordpress WP_Query on Author Page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I want to build an author.php which displays two different loops:

The #1 Loop shall display all Posts from an Author which are made with the Custom Post Type "News".

The #2 Loop shall displayy all Posts from the Author which are made through a normal Post.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) :     get_userdata(intval($author)); ?>
```

This line will identify the current Author... And here are my Loops:

## 1

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'news','author=$curauth->ID','posts_per_page' => -1 ); ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
```

## 2

```
    <?php
$query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'post','author=$curauth-  >ID','posts_per_page' => -1 ));
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
```

The Problem with this is the >>'`author=$curauth-  >ID`'<< doesn´t work in the string, i guess. It outputs ALL the posts and doesn't separate between different authors.

Comment: `$args = array( 'post_type' => 'news','author=' . $curauth->ID,'posts_per_page' => -1 );`

Comment: You have spaces between $curauth- and >ID. remove those spaces. You can use 'author' as array index.

Comment: Hmm, the spaces are just on stackoverflow not in my source. I've tried your snippet but it still won't work :(

Comment: use 'author' as index. Also see if there is correct value in $curauth->ID.

Comment: `<?php $query = new WP_Query(array( 'author' => 'author=' . $curauth->ID ,'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => -1 )); ?>` I´ve tried it like this. Now there are 0 Posts outputted :/

Comment: Makes sense and works. Thank you guys! :)

Comment: Hi, if its solved you should post your own answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use usual WP loop whith

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

And add:

```
wp_reset_query();
```

after first list.

In this case I don't think you need custum WP_QUery and if you keep it sample this may remove some bug or error.

Hope this will help